# Obtener ultima fila de datos en una consulta

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

tengo la siguiente consulta

```
SELECT
    num_cotizacion,
    CONCAT(num_cotizacion,'-',num_modificacion) AS correlativo,
    nombre_contacto,
    cargo_contacto,
    rut_empresa,
    razon_social,
    fecha_registro,
    IF( estado_cotizacion = 1,'Aceptado',IF ( estado_cotizacion = 2, 'Rechazado', 'Pendiente')) AS estado_cotizacion,
    IF( estado_solicitud = 1,'Aceptado',IF ( estado_solicitud = 2, 'Rechazado', IF ( estado_solicitud = 3, 'Pendiente', 'N/A'))) AS estado_solicitud,
    IF( estado_enviado = 0,'NO', 'SI') AS estado_enviado,
    IF(DATE_ADD( fecha_registro,INTERVAL  dias_vencimiento DAY) <= now(),'SI','NO') AS vencimiento FROM
    cot_cabedoc_hist /*GROUP BY num_cotizacion*/ ORDER BY fecha_registro ASC
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero es mostrar todos los registros agrupados por el num_cotizacion pero con los datos del último número num_modificacion (correlativo).

Por ejemplo, el num_cotizacion 1 tiene dos correlativos 1-1 y 1-2, lo cual quiero que se muestre solo la fila 1-2 con sus datos.

Comment: ¿La tabla `cot_cabedoc_hist` tiene alguna columna `auto-increment`? Es decir, un `id` único De ser así, ¿como se llama dicha columna?

Answer (score 2):

Como no indicas si la tabla `cot_cabedoc_hist` tiene una columna con un `id` único para cada registro, lo que podrías hacer es:

- Buscar los registros agrupados por `num_cotizacion` y su `MAX(num_modificacion)` (*Consulta A*)
- Unir dichos resultados a la tabla `cot_cabedoc_hist` donde sus `num_cotizacion` y `num_modificacion` coincidan (*JOIN B*).
- Para que la unión sea más eficiente, es mejor crear un indice sobre ambas columnas.

  ```
  ALTER TABLE cot_cabedoc_hist ADD INDEX (`num_cotizacion`, `num_modificacion`);
  ```

#### Ejemplo:

```
SELECT
    num_cotizacion,
    CONCAT(num_cotizacion,'-',num_modificacion) AS correlativo,
    nombre_contacto,
    cargo_contacto,
    rut_empresa,
    razon_social,
    fecha_registro,
    IF( estado_cotizacion = 1,'Aceptado',IF ( estado_cotizacion = 2, 'Rechazado', 'Pendiente')) AS estado_cotizacion,
    IF( estado_solicitud = 1,'Aceptado',IF ( estado_solicitud = 2, 'Rechazado', IF ( estado_solicitud = 3, 'Pendiente', 'N/A'))) AS estado_solicitud,
    IF( estado_enviado = 0,'NO', 'SI') AS estado_enviado,
    IF(DATE_ADD( fecha_registro,INTERVAL  dias_vencimiento DAY) <= now(),'SI','NO') AS vencimiento
FROM (
    SELECT num_cotizacion,
        MAX(num_modificacion) AS num_modificacion
    FROM cot_cabedoc_hist
    GROUP BY num_cotizacion
) AS A 
    INNER JOIN cot_cabedoc_hist AS B
       USING (`num_cotizacion`, `num_modificacion`)
ORDER BY fecha_registro ASC
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/intfLqcA7wr9veZKkcwuYo/0)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Con base en los resultados que muestras de primera instancia no podríamos hacer un **`GROUP BY`** ya que algunos de los elementos en las celdas no son los mismos aunque pertenecen al mismo **`numero_cotizacion`**.

Dicho lo anterior lo que podemos hacer es trabajar con:

```
GROUP_CONCAT
```

Esta función de *MySQL* y presente también en *MariaDB* nos permitirá agrupar concatenando valores que incluso podemos separar por algún símbolo.

Dado eso y entonces conociendo que tenemos columnas como:

- correlativo
- nombre_contacto
- cargo_contacto

Deberás por cada una de ellas hacer uso de dicha función y pasarla como argumento  y opcionalmente **`SEPARATOR`** indicando entre comillas que valor separará cada uno de los registros que se concentren ahí.

**Ejemplo**

```
GROUP_CONCAT(correlativo SEPARATOR '/')
```

**Fuente de consulta**

- [Función **`GROUP_CONCAT`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)